# In objective-c, how can I tell the difference between a Class and an instance of a class?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

Let's say I have a generic pointer in objective-c. This pointer could either be a `Class` object, or it could be an *instance* of that class. Is there any way to tell the difference between the two?

Example:

```
id pointerA = [someClass class];
id pointerB = [[someClass alloc] init];

bool pointerAIsAClass = is_this_a_Class(pointerA); // should be true
bool pointerBIsAClass = is_this_a_Class(pointerB); // should be false
```

How would I write the `is_this_a_Class` function so that it returns the proper `bool` value?

```
bool is_this_a_Class(id somePointer)
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most correct way is to check the class of the object, and see if it's a metaclass:

```
BOOL object_isClass(id object) {
    return class_isMetaClass(object_getClass(object));
}
```

There are more answers here: [Check if object is Class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536244/check-if-object-is-class-type)

Comment: Cool. That does look like the correct approach. Thank you for taking the time to answer a question from almost three years ago!

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a better way, and this isn't foolproof, but this should work:

```
BOOL pointer_isClass(id object) {
    return [object respondsToSelector:@selector(instancesRespondToSelector:)];
}
```

Since, theoretically, only `Class` objects would respond to the `-instancesRespondToSelector:` message this should work. Outside of an actual `objc_*` call though I don't see any real API for this.

**UPDATE:**

After reading Giao's answer another thought came to me, test the pointer's response to the `-class` method. Calling `-class` on a class object should be equivalent to calling `-self` on an object instance but would return another object on an object instance.

```
BOOL pointer_isClass(id object) {
    return object == [object class];
}
```

I think this should be more foolproof, especially in the case where an object instance implements `-instancesRespondToSelector:` this one should work 100% of the time.

Comment: Beautiful. Your new method works and is much more elegant. Thanks again :)

Comment: There's a bunch of useful information about this type of thing here:

http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html

Comment: These answers assume that the methods `class` and `instancesRespondToSelector` are available, which is only true for `NSObject`. Plus, there is no guarantee that a class cannot, for example, override those methods you use above to trick your function.