# How to check a class in a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios

In the below dictionary I want to write a condition for type class, Is there any way to identify the class type alone in the iteraction

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:@"check",@"checkValue",@"webservice", [webservice class], @"list",@"listValue", nil, @"task", [task class], @"new", @"newValue", @"operation",[operation class]];

  for(NSString *aKey in dictionary) {        

        if ([[dictionary valueForKey:aKey]) {
            NSLog(@"Getting In");
        }

    }
```

**Note :I want a single condition to check values [webservice class],[task class],[operation class]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer for my question in the below link

[Check if object is Class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536244/check-if-object-is-class-type)

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:@"check",@"checkValue",@"webservice", [webservice class], @"list",@"listValue", nil, @"task", [task class], @"new", @"newValue", @"operation",[operation class]];

  for(NSString *aKey in dictionary) {        

        if (class_isMetaClass(object_getClass(obj))) {
            NSLog(@"Getting In");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Look up -isKindOfClass: and -isMemberOfClass:

```
if([object isKindOfClass:[AObjectClass class])
{
    NSLog(@"object is of type AObjectClass");
}
```

See the [Apple isKindOfClass: documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

Comment: It is used to check a particular class, I just want generic solution to check whether its a class alone

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)isMemberOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

this is what u seek probably.

For example, in this code, isMemberOfClass: would return NO:

```
NSMutableData *myData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:30];
id anArchiver = [[NSArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:myData];
if ([anArchiver isMemberOfClass:[NSCoder class]])
    //something...
```

ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

---

Edit:

In NSDictionaries you will have to put Strings for keys. I suggest you convert the class to a string with `NSStringFromClass([MyClass class]);` and put that as a key.

The way you want to use the class as a key is impossible.

Comment: It is used to check a particular class, I just want generic solution to check whether its a class alone

Comment: @Nakkeeran: the way you want to use the class as a key is impossible i suggest a work-around using the method in my answer as key.