# Retrieve class of a NSDictionary object

Tags: objective-c, class, nsdictionary

Why does the following code returns not a `NSDictionary`, but a `__NSDictionaryI`?

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
Class c = [dict class];
NSLog(@"%@", c);
```

What are my options to check if an object is an instance of `NSDictionary`? As I've found out, I can't call `[__NSDictionaryI class]` because it's not visible.

`[dict classForCoder]` returns `NSDictionary` and seems to be a good solution, but won't it fail when calling on object of some custom class? What is the most universal method to check if an object is an instance of a given class?

Answer (score 2):

According to header that can be found [here](https://github.com/Musixmatchdev/ObjectiveHeaders/blob/master/Headers/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/CoreFoundation/__NSDictionaryI.h) __NSDictionaryI is descendant of NSDictionary, so I guess you can use this check:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
//your code here
}
```

and it should work with NSDictionary and __NSDictionaryI instances.

Comment: And with __NSDictionaryM which is a NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 1):

[How to check a class in a NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879129/how-to-check-a-class-in-a-nsdictionary)

```
if([object isKindOfClass:[AObjectClass class])
{
    NSLog(@"object is of type AObjectClass");
}
```