# Distinguish between an instance and a Class

Tags: objective-c

Basically, my problem is this:

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)object;
```

Ideally, I would use my method like this:

```
NSObject*theObject;
[MysteryObject aMethod:theObject];
```

or like this:

```
[MysteryObject aMethod:NSObject];
```

Basically, that is the question. How can I distinguish if an 'id' variable holds simply a Class type or a pointer to a live object?

Comment: Objective-C and C aren't related like this...the `C` tag should be taken off.

Comment: It's a pretty clear question - I don't know why it's being voted for closing.

Comment: The second code snippet should read `[MysteryObject aMethod:[NSObject class]];`, otherwise it would be a compilation error.

Comment: I have answered this question here: [Check if object is Class type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536244/check-if-object-is-class-type/6537756#6537756)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if ([MysteryObject respondsToSelector:@selector(isSubclassOfClass:)])
    NSLog(@"is a class");
else
    NSLog(@"is an object");
```

But in fact, to be more duck type friendly, you should probably use `respondsToSelector` to check for the message you're actually going to send.

Comment: This should work, but it will need to be called like this: `[MysteryObject aMethod:[NSObject class]]` when giving it a class rather than an object.

Answer (score 0):

Although using runtime functions is perfectly fine, I believe this is a much simpler way to achieve the same result:

```
- (void) aMethod:(id)anObject
{
  if( anObject == [anObject class] ) {
    // the object is a class
  }
  else {
    // the object is an instance object
  }
}
```