# In Cocoa, how is the Class type defined?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

From "objc.h":

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

but in "runtime.h":

```
struct objc_class {
    Class isa;

#if !__OBJC2__
    Class super_class                                        OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    const char *name                                         OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long version                                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long info                                                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    long instance_size                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_ivar_list *ivars                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_method_list **methodLists                    OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_cache *cache                                 OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    struct objc_protocol_list *protocols                     OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
#endif

} OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
/* Use `Class` instead of `struct objc_class *` */
```

What exactly is `Class`?

Comment: The `typedef` suggests that it is a pointer to `struct objc_class`, no?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight He's probably confused about `Class` being a member of `struct objc_class`.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused - please could you explain to me what it really is? Because I thought it's kind of circular reference between those two headers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

^ That is a forward declaration for an `objc_class` pointer. It gives it the nice friendly name `Class`.

Now lets take a look at the `objc_class` struct:
(Removing Objective-C 2.0 checks to shorten it up)

```
struct objc_class {
    Class isa;
};
//This is really saying
struct objc_class {
    struct objc_class *isa;
};
```

So now we have a struct that points to its own type. But why you ask?

*Taken from [Inside the Objective-C Runtime, Part 2](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2002/05/31/runtime_parttwo.html?page=2)*

> The Class pointed to by the Class' isa (the Class' Class) contains the
>   Class' class methods in its objc_method_list. Got that? The
>   terminology used in the runtime is that while an object's isa points
>   to its Class, a Class's isa points to the object's "meta Class".
>
> So what about a meta Class' isa pointer? Well, that points to the root
>   class of the hierarchy (NSObject in most cases). (In the Foundation
>   framework each meta class of a subclass of NSObject "isa" instance of
>   NSObject.) And yes, by the way, NSObject's meta Class' isa points back
>   to the same struct -- it's a circular reference so no Class' isa is
>   ever NULL.

---

So according to that description when you create a class inheriting from `NSObject` you have an `isa` that points to its class type which points to its meta class which points to its root class (`NSObject`) which contains a circular reference to itself. This explains the reason why it [requires two steps to determine if an object is an instance or a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536244/check-if-object-is-class-type/6537756#6537756).

Lets say you create the following class:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end
@implementation MyClass
@end
```

If you were able* to traverse the isa pointer you would get the following:
*<sub>You can not since the `isa` is protected. See Cocoa with Love post below for creating your own implementation.</sub>

```
Class c = myClassInstance->isa; //This would be the MyClass
c = c->isa; //This would be MyClass' meta class
c = c->isa; //This would be NSObjects meta class
c = c->isa; //This going forward would still be the NSObjects meta class
...
```

Once `c == c->isa` you will know you are at the root object. Remember that Objective-C is a proper superset of C, which does not natively have object-oriented constructs such as inheritance. This along with other implementation details, such as pointers to super classes which make up the full class hierarchy, allows Objective-C to provide object-oriented features. For more information on classes and meta-classes see the post on Cocoa with Love: [What is a meta-class in Objective-C?](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html)

Comment: Nice answer, but one little thing... If the OP's code is correct then "Removing Objective-C 2.0 checks to shorten it up" removes the *whole* definition - note the final `OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE` on the `struct` itself.

Comment: Yes, it does and you are not supposed to use the `objc_class` struct at all. It is still mandatory that every class has an `isa` as its first member so I just added a short version of the struct for an example. The rest of the details are all implementation defined in `OBJC2`.

Answer (score 0):

about circular reference:

if isa is defined not a pointer as following, then that become a circular reference.

```
struct objc_class {
    struct objc_class isa;
};
```

because the compiler could not calc the size of objc_class.

But, in following case(real definition),

```
struct objc_class {
    struct objc_class *isa;
};
```

isa is just a pointer, so doesn't have the matter.