# regarding the "Class" class in obj-c?

Tags: objective-c

Please observe this method declaration:

```
NSString *NSStringFromClass(Class aClass);
```

I want to understand the `Class` class, but I can't find docs about it because I don't know how to create a good enough regular expression and google with it. The fact that the class name is `Class` and not `NSClass` makes me think `Class` is not a real class (like `java.lang.Class`). But, I don't know, and so I want to research this. But, I can't find docs.

If I need to ask *a specific question*:
is "Class" in obj-c a real class? what are its methods and properties?

Comment: It's one of those things that is well-hidden in the (rather poorly structured) Apple documentation, but it is pretty much analogous to Java's `Class` (to the extent that anything is analogous between Objective-C and Java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [Cocoa with Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html)

> Every object has a class. This is a fundamental object-oriented concept but in Objective-C, it is also a fundamental part of the data. Any data structure which has a pointer to a class in the right location can be treated as an object.
> In Objective-C, an object's class is determined by its `isa` pointer. The `isa` pointer points to the object's Class.

And as a proof of it, here's the declaration of `id` as a pointer to the `objc_object` struct.

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

So here we get to the point. What is a `Class`?

Let's look at the definition

`Class` is defined as follows (it may actually vary depending on the runtime, but let's keep it simple)

```
struct objc_class {
    Class isa;
}
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

As you can see a `Class` has a `isa` pointer as well. It looks suspiciously like the `objc_object` definition and the reason is simple: `Class` is in fact an object.

But what is the class of a `Class`? It's - by definition - a meta-class.

According to the same source (in bold the part that tackles your question directly),

> **The meta-class, like the `Class` before it, is also an object. This means that you can invoke methods on it too.** Naturally, this means that it must also have a class.
>
> All meta-classes use the base class' meta-class (the meta-class of the top `Class` in their inheritance hierarchy) as their class. This means that for all classes that descend from `NSObject` (most classes), the meta-class has the `NSObject` meta-class as its class.
>
> Following the rule that all meta-classes use the base class' meta-class as their class, any base meta-classes will be its own class (their isa pointer points to themselves). This means that the isa pointer on the `NSObject` meta-class points to itself (it is an instance of itself).

For further reading on the subject, here's another [great explanation](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html) by Greg Parker.

Comment: Thank you. Using these docs, I was able to find this thread which was extremely useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265375/in-cocoa-how-is-the-class-type-defined