# Determine whether argument is a class or a protocol

Tags: objective-c, class, protocols

I have the following method. I currently use try/catch blocks to determine whether the argument is a class or a protocol, and it seems like it's causing a memory leak. What's the correct way to determine whether `x` is a class or a protocol?

```
[self _injectMacro:[MyClass class]];
[self _injectMacro:@protocol(MyProtocol)];

+ (id)_injectMacro:(id)x
{
    @try {
        return NSStringFromProtocol(x);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }

    @try {
        return NSStringFromClass(x);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Neither method documents what occurs if the class/protocol does not exist.  Even if your code works today it might not tomorrow.

Comment: Cocoa is not, in general, exception-safe. Continuing after catching may cause problems -- such as memory leaks. On the other hand, those functions don't throw exceptions as far as I know. Does this code actually do what you expect?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks. You are right my code was alway going through the first try, and it was valid. When i switched the place of the two try-and-catch it started throwing EXC_Bad_Access, so it's not really catching the exception

Comment: I'd be surprised if those functions didn't just call straight through to the appropriate runtime functions, `class_getName()` and `protocol_getName()`, both of which try to dereference their argument, e.g., `return proto->name;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isKindOfClass` to find whether or not an `id` is a protocol:

```
id x = [NSObject class];
id y = @protocol(NSObject); 
NSLog(@"%d", [x isKindOfClass:[Protocol class]]); // 0
NSLog(@"%d", [y isKindOfClass:[Protocol class]]); // 1
```

You have to import the `ObjectiveC.Protocol` module to use `Protocol`:

```
@import ObjectiveC.Protocol;
```

Or if you are not using modules, just import the Protocol header:

```
#import <objc/Protocol.h>
```

To check if an `id` is a class or an instance have a look a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537756/1489997)

Comment: Getting a compile error on that import. Unexpected '@' in program

Comment: That's the new module syntax. Try `#import <objc/Protocol.h>`, @aryaxt.

Comment: @JoshCaswell doesn't seem to work, did it work for you?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks, I had to set 'enable module' to YES in build setting. It means any project that needs to use the code has to do the same. I'm wondering if there is another way. I'll use it for now. Thanks again for the quick answers

Comment: @aryaxt: As Josh pointed out, you can use the old `#import` syntax. I've updated my answer.